# Why am I getting this error of "Invalid command name while executing ("after" script)"?

Tags: python, tkinter, compiler-errors, customtkinter

I am trying to create an application with a login page using tkinter and customtkinter. Once the user logs in with valid creds they should be taken to their account page. Right now, it seems to be working as intended, but I keep also getting an error and I can't figure out why.

This is the code for the login page:

```
class LoginPage:
    def __init__(self) -> None:   
        self.root = ctk.CTk()  

        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 

        self.root.after(0, lambda:self.root.state('zoomed')) 
        self.root.title("Login Page") 

        bgImage = Image.open("bg.jpg")  
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImage) 
        bgLabel = tk.Label(self.root, image = bg)     
        bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)

        loginFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.root)     
        loginFrame.pack(pady = 120, padx = 500, fill = "both", expand = True)   

        loginLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(loginFrame, text="Login", font = ("Tahoma", 35, "bold"))
        loginLabel.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)

        self.usernameEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(loginFrame, placeholder_text="Username", font = ("Tahoma", 15), width = 300, height = 50)   
        self.usernameEntry.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)

        self.passwordEntry = ctk.CTkEntry(loginFrame, placeholder_text="Password", show = "*", font = ("Tahoma", 15), width = 300, height = 50)   
        self.passwordEntry.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10) 

        loginButton = ctk.CTkButton(loginFrame, text="Login", font = ("Tahoma", 15, "bold"), command = self.validateLogin, width = 300, height = 50)  
        loginButton.pack(pady = 30, padx = 10)   

        self.root.mainloop() 

    def validateLogin(self) -> None: 
        name = self.usernameEntry.get().lower() 

        if self.checkProvidedLogin(name, self.passwordEntry.get()): 
            self.root.destroy()  
            AccountPage(name)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror(message = "Invalid login, Try again") 

    def checkProvidedLogin(self, username, password) -> bool:
        with open('logins.csv', 'r') as file:
                logins = file.read().splitlines()
        for line in logins:   
             if line == username + "," + password: 
                  return True
        return False  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    LoginPage()
```

And this is the code for the account page:

```
class AccountPage:
    def __init__(self, username) -> None: 
        self.accountRoot = ctk.CTk() 

        ctk.set_appearance_mode("dark")
        ctk.set_default_color_theme("dark-blue") 

        self.accountRoot.after(0, lambda:self.accountRoot.state('zoomed')) 

        bgImage = Image.open("bg.jpg")  
        bg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(bgImage) 
        bgLabel = tk.Label(self.accountRoot, image = bg)    
        bgLabel.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1) 

        accountFrame = ctk.CTkFrame(self.accountRoot)
        accountFrame.pack(pady = 50, padx = 50, fill = "both", expand = True)   

        welcomeLabel = ctk.CTkLabel(accountFrame, text = f"Welcome, {username}!", font = ("Tahoma", 35, "bold"))
        welcomeLabel.pack(pady = 20)

        self.accountRoot.mainloop()
```

Again, the application works fine right now. When valid creds are input on the login page, the account page appears as it should. But I am also getting this error message:

```
invalid command name "2792697387712check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"2792697387712check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "2792697396224update"
    while executing
"2792697396224update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "2792696741952_click_animation"
    while executing
"2792696741952_click_animation"
    ("after" script)
```

Any ideas on what could be causing this?

I thought it might be something to do with me using destroy() on the login page in the validateLogin() function before creating an instance of AccountPage, but switching those around didn't really help.

Answer (score 0):

- So short answer the error lies when you destroy the root `self.root.destroy()`
  And to fix this you can either hide the window ( aka. move the window far far off the screen ) or make a 'copy' and destroy that instead.

The long answer and the solution.
Change the 'start-up' code to this. Which passes the variable root which will be used next

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = CTk()
    LoginPage(root)
```

This is the most important part. Your function should look like this. It will take the root and make a window. Of course, now change the object's parent to `self.loginWindow` and you can `self.loginWindow.destroy()` which won't cause any errors by removing the parent object of basically everything.

```
def __init__(self, root) -> None:   
    self.root = root
    self.loginWindow = Toplevel(root)
    set_appearance_mode("dark")
    set_default_color_theme("dark-blue")
```

hope this helps